# Disable ListView selection highligt when clicking on a button

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView` in my layout which highlights the current selected item. See figure below. On the click of a `Button`, I'd like for this highlight to disappear.

**Note:** I do not want to set the `selectionMode` of the `ListView` to `NONE`, I still want the `ListView` to display the current selected item as shown in the figure, when the user selects a new item in the list. Simply setting the `selectionMode` to `NONE` will not achieve the behavior which I strive for.

[image: List highlight selection]

ListView.xml:

```
<ListView
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:id="@+id/lw"
 />
```

I've tried setting the selection of the list view to -1, as below.

```
myListView.setSelection(-1);
```

However, this doesn't do the trick. The `ListView` still displays the selection.

Additionally, I've tried to setting the `selectionMode` to `NONE`, then switching it back to `SINGLE` again, like below. Still no dice.

```
lwNotes.setSelection(-1);
lwNotes.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
lwNotes.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

How do I reset/disable/disappear the highlight selection in my `ListView`, without removing the functionality for the user to highlight a new item afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

try using the `ListView`'s `listSelector` and `cacheColorHint` attributes as follows:

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Should I add this in my XML file, or add this attribute in my buttons `onClick`?

Comment: Add it to the ListView tag in the XML

Comment: Tried it, the highlight is still visable

Comment: I've edited my answer, please try adding the cacheColorHint attribute

Comment: The highlight is still there after I click the button